# Dynamic field or field of type (Struct, Map, Any) for custom options

Tags: protocol-buffers

Assuming I need to define a custom option for a method, for example:

```
message MessageBusOptions {
    string namespace = 1;
    optional string queue = 2; 
}

extend google.protobuf.MethodOptions {
   optional MessageBusOptions message_bus_options = 50000;
}
```

So far everything works as expected. I can define my service the following way:

```
services TestServices {
    rpc SendMessage(MessageReq) returns(MessageRes) {
        option (message_bus_options) = {
            namespace: "abc",
            queue: "default"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, how I can I add a dynamic field to the `MessageBusOptions` so that I can provide a dynamic value, for example:

```
services TestServices {
    rpc SendMessage(MessageReq) returns(MessageRes) {
        option (message_bus_options) = {
            namespace: "abc",
            queue: "default",
            dynamic_field: {
               a: "a",
               b: "b"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following types (Map, Any, Struct) but all of them led to this error

> Error while parsing option value for "xxx": Message type "xxx" has no field named "xxx".

How can I define such dynamic field in the custom option?